# Install ubuntu (or debian) on NTFS using posixovl

Tags: linux, mount, ntfs, initrd

I'm trying to install Xubuntu on my USB pen drive. I would like to use the pen drive as generic storage device as well, so I would like to keep it as a single NTFS partition for maximal compatibility with peripherals. I would also want to keep away from formatting a small ext3/4 partition for the linux root because that would be too easy, and will cause me to either over- or under-provision the size of it, wasting space or getting me into disk space shortage later on.

My idea was to mount the NTFS partition, and apply the [posixovl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/posixovl/) mount on it to get it posix compliant before installing to it.

Next I would have to modify the initrd to not only mount the NTFS filesystem somewhere, but also to apply the posixovl to it (mount it again). And then finally pivot_root into the posixovl mounted directory.

In theory I think this should work, but I have never toyed around with the initrd before, so how would I get started with this endavour?

Finally, how do I get my modifications to stick (assuming I get everything to install and work properly), so that I can perform any incoming updates, including kernel updates etc.

Comment: Don't use NTFS. Use UDF (Universal Disk Format) instead.

It supports POSIX, and it's supported by Windows, OS X, Linux, FreeBSD, All DVD/BluRAY players and most embedded devices.